# How to use jQuery to select text inside anchor tags

Tags: jquery, html, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I want to select the `a` tag and display its text when clicked.

In another word, when I click the first link - "One", I want to display its text "One" using `alert`.

When I click the second link - "Example", I want to display the text "Example" using `alert`.

```
<body>
    <div id="tree">
        <ul>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="one.html">One</a></li>
        <li class="folder expnded"><a target="_blank" href="two.html">Examples</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div id="display"></div>    
</body>
```

**Update 1:**

Thank everyone for answering. What I really want to do is that I need to create a tree structure and when I click tree leaf node, I have to display name of that leaf node.

I created tree structure using jQuery DynaTree, but jQuery selectors is not working for me in the code above.

I'm not able to select tags or any other elements inside the `div` tag.

Below is the tree structure:

[image]

### THIS IS MY FULL HTML CODE (above is just a sample code)

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Include the required JavaScript libraries: -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='js/myjquery.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui.dynatree.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery.dynatree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="tree">
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Google</a>
            <li class="folder expnded">Examples
                <ul>
                    <li><a target="content" href="" id="s">one</a>
                    <li><a target="content" href="two.html">two</a>
                    <li class="folder">Folder one
                        <ul>
                            <li><a target="content" href="one.html">one</a>
                            <li><a target="content" href="two.html">two</a>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a target="content" href="three.html">three</a>
                    <li><a target="content" href="four.html">four</a>
                    <li class="folder">Folder two
                        <ul>
                            <li><a target="content" href="one.html">one</a>
                            <li><a target="content" href="two.html">two</a>
                        </ul>
                    <li class="folder">Folder three
                        <ul>
                            <li><a target="content" href="one.html">one</a>
                            <li><a target="content" href="two.html">two</a>
                            <li class="folder">Inner Folder
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a target="content" href="one.html">one</a>
                                    <li><a target="content" href="two.html">two</a>
                                </ul>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="display">
    <a href="" id="s">one</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The picture I posted is the output of above HTML code.

In myjquery.js file I have code (old) like this

```
$(function() {
        // --- Initialize sample trees
        $("#tree").dynatree({
            autoFocus : true,
            //          persist: true,
            minExpandLevel : 2,
            onFocus : function(node) {
                // Auto-activate focused node after 1 second
                if (node.data.href) {
                    node.scheduleAction("activate", 1000);
                }
            },
            onBlur : function(node) {
                node.scheduleAction("cancel");
            },
            onActivate : function(node) {
                if (node.data.href) {
                    window.open(node.data.href, node.data.target);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Update 2:**

### solution for my problem

In myjquery.js file, the following new code works for me. You can compare it with old code above.

```
$(function() {
    // --- Initialize sample trees
    $("#tree").dynatree({
        autoFocus : true,
         persist: true,
        minExpandLevel : 1,
        onFocus : function(node) {
            // Auto-activate focused node after 1 second
            if (node.data.href) {
                node.scheduleAction("activate", 1000);
            }
        },
        onBlur : function(node) {
            node.scheduleAction("cancel");
        },
        onActivate : function(node) {
            if (node.data.href) {
                window.open(node.data.href, node.data.target);
            }
        },
        onClick : function(node) {
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "Display",
                data : {
                    id : node.data.title
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    $("#display").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you still want to redirect the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a', '#tree li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();    // this line is for prevent page reload
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/163/)**

Read more about [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) and [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)

#### According to edit

You can try like below:

```
$('span[class^=dynatree-exp-c] a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Each leaf node of dynatree is span that has class like `dynatree-exp-c`, `dynatree-exp-c1` etc, so I use `[class^=dynatree-exp-c]` to select that span whose class start with `dynatree-exp-c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script.

```
jQuery('a').click(function(){
   var x = jQuery(this).text();
    alert(x);
});​
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5rTTN/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    alert( $(this).text() );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```